# array.split to create a string with multiple whitespaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, whitespace

I am trying to create several strings comprising of varying amounts of whitespaces only. I have been able to do this once with array.(number of indexes).join(" ");

However when I go into a loop to add more strings with an incrementing amount of white space in each string, the string is set to 'undefined.' I am not sure where I am going wrong. The function seems to work outside of the loop but not inside. Any ideas what I have done wrong?

```js
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
    // build here
    var towers = [];
    var stars = "*";
    var spaceNo = nFloors -1;
    let spaces = Array(spaceNo).join(" ");
    spaceNo -= 1;
    towers[0] = spaces + stars + spaces;
    for(i = 1; i <= nFloors -1; i++)
    {
      stars = stars + Array(i + 2).join('*');
      let edges = Array(spaceNo).join(" ");
      towers[i] = edges + stars + edges;
      spaceNo -= 1;
    }
    

    return towers;
}
console.log(towerBuilder(3));
```

At the top, this works:

```
 let spaces = Array(spaceNo).join(" ");
```

However, down in the loop, this outputs 'undefined'

```
let edges = Array(spaceNo).join(" ");
```

The idea is that the spaces wrap the star symbols so that a tower can be built out of an array. Example, calling towerBuilder(3) would output the below: (I don't need to output it with carriage returns. The array alone will suffice.)

```
[
  '  *  ', 
  ' *** ', 
  '*****'
]
```

Comment: *"owever, down in the loop, this outputs 'undefined'"* Not in the code you've posted. I took it and dropped it into a Stack Snippet, and it doesn't do what you describe. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (ideally using Stack Snippets as I did; [here's more info about them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: What output are you getting? I am expecting to see spaces wrapped around the stars on each line but I only get the below.
[
  " * ",
  "***",
  "******"
]

Comment: Which isn't `undefined`. Your question says *"this outputs 'undefined'"*. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.join` is used to concatenate all the array's values, with the given string between them:

`['foo','bar'].join(',') // = 'foo,bar'`

You are expecting `Array(2).join(' ')` to be two spaces, but it will be only one since it's concatenating two empty values with a space in between.

Just remove the `-1` at row 5 and it will work as expected:

```js
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
    // build here
    var towers = [];
    var stars = "*";
    var spaceNo = nFloors; // was nFloors - 1
    let spaces = Array(spaceNo).join(" ");
    spaceNo -= 1;
    towers[0] = spaces + stars + spaces;
    for(i = 1; i <= nFloors -1; i++)
    {
      stars = stars + Array(i + 2).join('*');
      let edges = Array(spaceNo).join(" ");
      towers[i] = edges + stars + edges;
      spaceNo -= 1;
    }
    

    return towers;
}
console.log(towerBuilder(3));
```

Btw, it would look a lot better if written like this:

```js
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
    // build here
    var towers = [];
    
    for(var floor = 0; floor < nFloors; floor++)
    {
      var nStars = (floor * 2) + 1;
      var stars = Array(nStars + 1).join('*');
      var edges = Array(nFloors - floor).join(" ");
      towers[floor] = edges + stars + edges;
    }

    return towers;
}
console.log(towerBuilder(3));
```